# How to bind file path to file upload in Jquery MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

While editing the form I need to get the file path and bind to file upload control.

This is html:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="uploadCFile" class="form-control input-validation-error" style="width:300px" data-val="true" />
```

This is my jquery code

```
 $("#uploadCFile").val(jdata.cInfo.FilePath);
```

Error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Comment: Try look into  ng-file-select, good luck.

//$files: an array of files selected
<input type="file" ng-file-select="prepareUploadFiles($files)">

Comment: The error is telling you the truth. You can't set a file input value for security reasons

Comment: @charlie, I understood your user answers. but how to handle this scenario? Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: Not without more knowledge of your process flow